# TypeError: argument of type 'Tensor' is not iterable

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am getting this error while trying to make prediction on test data from my model.
Code:

```
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=42)

data_generator=ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=20, # rotate the image 20 degrees
                               width_shift_range=0.10, # Shift the pic width by a max of 5%
                               height_shift_range=0.10, # Shift the pic height by a max of 5%
                               rescale=1/255, # Rescale the image by normalzing it.
                               shear_range=0.1, # Shear means cutting away part of the image (max 10%)
                               zoom_range=0.1, # Zoom in by 10% max
                               horizontal_flip=True,
                               vertical_flip=True,
                               fill_mode='nearest')

data_generator.fit(x_train)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.Input(shape=(28, 28,3), name='feature'),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(7, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

adv_config = nsl.configs.make_adv_reg_config(multiplier=0.2, adv_step_size=0.05)
adv_model = nsl.keras.AdversarialRegularization(model, adv_config=adv_config)

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1.0e-4)

adv_model.compile(optimizer=opt,
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

adv_model.fit(x={'feature': x_train, 'label': y_train}, batch_size=42, epochs=50)

res = adv_model.predict(x_test)
```

What do I need to do to get this error resolved?
Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

First use print(type(tensor_name)) to see the type of error. Tensor

My Tensor type is: <class ‘tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor’>, and the conversion type is required: <class ‘numpy.ndarray’>

The following statement performs a type conversion:
#convert to numpy array
tensor_name=tensor_name.eval(session=sess)
1  `sess=tf.Session()`
2`#convert to numpy array`
3`tensor_name=tensor_name.eval(session=sess)`
Use print(type(tensor_name)) again to see the type of tensor_name

Comment: Tensor is already of type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Answer (score 0):

I changed the input in predict function and now it is working.
`res = adv_model.predict(x={'feature': x_test, 'label': y_test})`